# Relationship between Coefficients of Orthogonal Polynomial and Normal regression

Tags: regression, polynomial

So this is more a question to help me understand what is going on rather than application:

So in normal regression we have

$$
\mathbf{Y=X} \mathbf{\beta} +   \varepsilon
$$

Now the part that really confuses me:

A regression with orthogonal polynomial regression is just:

$$
\mathbf{Y= \phi(X)} \mathbf{W}+   \varepsilon
$$

where $ \mathbf{\phi(X) = P^{T} X}$ and $W= \mathbf{P\beta}$

Where P is the orthonormal change of basis matrix that you can obtain in R using contri.poly()?These P transformations chosen usually appear to also centre the data? Also if I am correct, how exactly are these change of basis matrix determined?